# Magento2 - How to Export mysql database without products,orders and customers data?

Tags: magento2, database, export

I have one bigger website it has lot's of products, orders and customers.

I have to export database without products, orders and customers.
And have to import database in my local machine.

I follow this command to export data. this example for single table only.

> mysqldump -u root -p database
>   --ignore-table=database.frst_catalogrule_product > export.sql
>
> mysqldump -u root -p database --no-data frst_catalogrule_product >>
>   export.sql

Now my question is

> How many tables are effected for product,orders and
>   customer? I need list of tables which are related to all of them?

So I can ignore those tables data and export rest.

I found list of products related tables. But i am not sure how many tables are important.

```
catalogrule_product
catalogrule_product_price
catalogrule_product_price_replica
catalogrule_product_replica
catalog_category_product
catalog_category_product_index
catalog_category_product_index_replica
catalog_category_product_index_tmp
catalog_product_bundle_option
catalog_product_bundle_option_value
catalog_product_bundle_price_index
catalog_product_bundle_selection
catalog_product_bundle_selection_price
catalog_product_bundle_stock_index
catalog_product_entity
catalog_product_entity_datetime
catalog_product_entity_decimal
catalog_product_entity_gallery
catalog_product_entity_int
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video
catalog_product_entity_text
catalog_product_entity_tier_price
catalog_product_entity_varchar
catalog_product_frontend_action
catalog_product_index_eav
catalog_product_index_eav_decimal
catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx
catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_replica
catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp
catalog_product_index_eav_idx
catalog_product_index_eav_replica
catalog_product_index_eav_tmp
catalog_product_index_price
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx
catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx
catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp
catalog_product_index_price_final_idx
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please find the below list of table related to product, order review and customer.

Or you can run the below query for remove the data from the table by taking the database backup.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

**Order tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `gift_message`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `reporting_orders`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_updated`;
```

**Customer tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_grid_flat`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_visitor`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `persistent_session`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist_item_option`;
```

**Review tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `review`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_detail`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_entity_summary`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_store`;
```

**Product tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_compare_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_price_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_stock_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_relation`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_compared_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_index`;
```

**Set Foreign key**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Magerun 2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) to do it running this command below:

```
curl -O https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar
./n98-magerun2.phar db:dump --strip="catalog_product* @customers @development"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is two great open source tools which may help you migrate M2 data base on the right way
- https://github.com/semaio/Magento2-ConfigImportExport 
- https://github.com/meanbee/magedbm2